# C# Как сделать постоянный обмен по Serial Port'у, который бы не прерывался при нажатиях кнопок на главной форме?

Tags: c#

Всем привет, программисты)
Мне нужен постоянный обмен по последовательному порту и чтобы он никак не зависел от прочей активности в программе, ну или хотя бы не сильно. Но у меня это сделать никак не получается. Я пробовал и стандартный компонент SerialPort, и другие варианты с использованием Win32API. Как мог разделял потоки, устанавливал приоритеты. В целом у меня не получается ничего.ниже привожу фотки осциллограм передачи. На Рис.1, как видите, идёт более-менее стабильная передача. А на Рис. 2 она прерывается, т.к я нажимал кнопку формы.
Что мне сделать чтобы такого не было?

[image: Рис.1]

[image: Рис.2]

Comment: Выделяйте передачу в отдельный поток

Comment: А где `Рис.1` и `Рис.2`?

Comment: Вот добавил рисунки

Comment: Если ваше общение с портом происходит в отдельном потоке, то задержек быть не должно. Проблема в другом месте.

Answer (score -1):

Решил проблему. 
Сначала я использовал такой вариант отправки:

```
while (true)
{
    SerialPort.Write(bytes);
    Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
}
```

Но именно этот вызов Thread.Sleep и сбоил. Я не знаю почему, но такой вариант нельзя использовать, он нерабочий. Нашел нативный таймер (не из пространств имен Timers, Threading и Windows.Forms), использующий методы COM, и проблема решилась. 
Теперь у меня работают найденные в сети нативные таймер и SerialPort, а также я использую очереди и межпоточную синхронизацию, и теперь моя программа может передавать с интервалами в 9 мс (~110 фреймов в секунду). Хотя можно и еще быстрее, если сократить кол-во передаваемых байт во фрейме (у меня передается 38 байт при скорости 115200, что занимает около 7 мс). Гонял сутки - ни разу не выдавал каких-либо исключений. Но есть недостаток, когда программа пытается открыть недоступный порт или передать фрейм через неоткрытый порт, то сразу выкидывает, и не успеваешь даже тип исключению выловить

Хороший таймер, который не нагружает cpu и четко держит интервалы:
[Millisecond Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31612770/7763753)

Comment: Thread.Sleep очень даже рабочий! Просто квант времени в винде по умолчанию - 20 мс :-)

Comment: Кстати, ваш ответ был бы намного полезнее если бы вы указали что за чудо-таймер вы нашли.

Comment: Ты не прав сейчас. Во-первых он 16 мс, а во-вторых даже если так, можно выставить Sleep(5) и все как бы будет работать, но нестабильно, я пробовал. Дело не в кванте, а в чем-то другом. Если запускать на передачу такой вариант со Sleep(5), например, 100 раз. То из них 50% будет правильно передавать, а 50% будет прерываться. Т.е зависит не от минимального кванта, от пула потоков - он каждый раз как-то по-разному потоки в программе настраивает

Comment: Вызвать-то можно с любым аргументом, но рассчитывать что разбудят через указанное время - слишком наивно

Comment: Ну да, я теперь это понял